# Implications of Indistinguishability of Particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, identical-particles

Wikipedia comments [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles#Statistical_effects_of_indistinguishability) on the effects of indistinguishibility of particles. Namely, it talks about the distribution of states after allowing the system (here two two level systems) interact and randomize with the environment. It says that for two identical bosons, the probability that the system will occupy the $|{0}\rangle |{0}\rangle$ state is $\frac{1}{3}$. This confuses me.

Namely I'm tempted to compare this to the situation of having two children, where even if we throw away the labels numbering the children, the probability of having two boys is $\frac{1}{4}$. What's the error in my thinking?

Comment: The error in your analogy is that even if you blindfolded yourself so that you could not distinguish between your children, your children would remain distinguishable...

Comment: Indeed, I just realized. Things are distinguishable, independent of whether or not I choose to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

If the two particles are indistinguishable, there is no distinction between the two states $|0\rangle |1\rangle$ and $|1\rangle |0\rangle$ (as it would be in the case of distinguishable particles.

So in fact, there are only three possible states: $|0\rangle |0\rangle$, $|1\rangle |1\rangle$ and the superposition $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle |1\rangle + |1\rangle |0\rangle\right)$. Each of these three states then has the same probability (in a randomized outcome), which is $\frac{1}{3}$.